# Quip Tutorial build error

Tags: quip

I followed the sticky note tutorial written in the official document [here](https://quip.com/dev/liveapps), but I get this error when I do `npm run build`. How can I solve this error?

```
ERROR in ./src/App.jsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/my-app/src/App.jsx: Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (4:22):

  2 | 
  3 | export default class App extends React.Component {
> 4 |     static propTypes = {
    |                      ^
  5 |         richTextRecord: PropTypes.instanceOf(quip.apps.RichTextRecord).isRequired,
  6 |     }
  7 |
```

The full output is this:

```
MacBook-Pro$ npm run build

> my-app@0.0.1 build
> NODE_ENV=production webpack; create-quip-app pack ./app

[webpack-cli] Compilation finished
Hash: a45f17b4ab6ed6fb9581
Version: webpack 4.44.2
Time: 1033ms
Built at: 10/21/2020 10:28:31 PM
     Asset      Size  Chunks         Chunk Names
    app.js  17.9 KiB       0         main
app.js.map  40.4 KiB       0  [dev]  main
Entrypoint main = app.js app.js.map
[0] external "quip" 42 bytes {0} [built]
[1] ./src/App.jsx 2.84 KiB {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]
[2] multi regenerator-runtime/runtime ./src/root.jsx 40 bytes {0} [built]
[3] ./node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js 24 KiB {0} [built]
[4] ./src/root.jsx 3.83 KiB {0} [built]

ERROR in ./src/App.jsx
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/my-app/src/App.jsx: Support for the experimental syntax 'classProperties' isn't currently enabled (4:22):

  2 | 
  3 | export default class App extends React.Component {
> 4 |     static propTypes = {
    |                      ^
  5 |         richTextRecord: PropTypes.instanceOf(quip.apps.RichTextRecord).isRequired,
  6 |     }
  7 | 

Add @babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4SL) to the 'plugins' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-class-properties (https://git.io/vb4yQ) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
    at Object._raise (/Users/my-app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:799:17)
    at Object.raiseWithData (/Users/my-app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:792:17)
    at Object.expectPlugin (/Users/my-app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:9094:18)
    at Object.parseClassProperty (/Users/my-app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12636:12)
    at Object.pushClassProperty (/Users/my-app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12600:30)
    at Object.parseClassMemberWithIsStatic (/Users/my-app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12507:14)
    at Object.parseClassMember (/Users/my-app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12444:10)
    at /Users/my-app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12389:14
    at Object.withTopicForbiddingContext (/Users/my-app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:11417:14)
    at Object.parseClassBody (/Users/my-app/node_modules/@babel/parser/lib/index.js:12366:10)
 @ ./src/root.jsx 24:0-28 58:54-57
 @ multi regenerator-runtime/runtime ./src/root.jsx
Built package at './app/app.ele'
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = require("quip-apps-webpack-config");
```

**App.jsx**

```
import Styles from "./App.less";

export default class App extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        richTextRecord: PropTypes.instanceOf(quip.apps.RichTextRecord).isRequired,
    }

    render() {
        const style = {
                backgroundColor: `${quip.apps.ui.ColorMap.YELLOW.VALUE_LIGHT}`,
                border: `1px solid ${quip.apps.ui.ColorMap.YELLOW.VALUE}`,
                boxShadow: "0 2px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)",
                padding: 10,
        };

        return <div className={Styles.hello} style={style}>
            <quip.apps.ui.RichTextBox
                record={this.props.richTextRecord}
                width={280}
                minHeight={280}
                maxHeight={280}/>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

**root.jsx**

```
import quip from "quip";
import App from "./App.jsx";

class StickyNoteRoot extends quip.apps.RootRecord {
    static getProperties() {
        return {
            stickyNote: quip.apps.RichTextRecord
        };
    }
}
quip.apps.registerClass(StickyNoteRoot, "root");

quip.apps.initialize({
    initializationCallback: function(rootNode) {
        let rootRecord = quip.apps.getRootRecord();
        if (params.isCreation) {
            rootRecord.set("stickyNote", {});
        }
        ReactDOM.render(
            <App richTextRecord={rootRecord.get("stickyNote")}/>,
            rootNode);
    },
});
```

**Spec**

- create-quip-app@0.0.45
- webpack 4.44.2
- npm@7.0.3 Mac, macOS Catalina Version 10.15.2
- node v15.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the file called `babel.config.js` in the root directly with the following code solved the problem.

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        '@babel/preset-env',
        '@babel/preset-react',
    ],
    plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties'
    ]
};
```